# check box not visible in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

[image]

VF Page:

```
<apex:page Controller="actionSupportController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}"/>          
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Characteristics Information">
            
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Active__c}" />Active<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Good_with_Cats__c}" />Good with Cats<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.HighNeed__c}" />HighNeed<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.kid_friendly__c}" />Kid Friendly<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Non_shedder__c}" />Non Shedder<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sct.Predatory_Tendencies__c}" />Prediator Tendency<br/>
            
            <br/><apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!dochar}" rerender="sblck"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputPanel id="sblck">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results">
                <apex:pageBlockTable width="80%" value="{!selctchr}" var="eachpe">
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Name__c}"/>
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Gender__c}"/>
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Height__c}"/>       
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.pet__c}"/>
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c}"/>
                    <apex:column width="80%" value="{!eachpe.Pet_ID__r.Status__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:commandButton value="Request Adoption"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class actionSupportController {
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;} 
    public List<PCS_Household__c> OnlstQuery{get;set;}
    public List<Characteristics__c> selctchr{get;set;}
    public Characteristics__c sct{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}      
    public string test{get;set;}
   
    public List<Pets_Information__c> selctpet{get;set;}
    
    Public Boolean Good{get;set;}
    

    
    public void dochar(){
        string query='';
        query='SELECT Name,ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c=:Good';
         system.debug('==query=='+query);
        selctchr=Database.query(query);    
        system.debug('==selctchr=='+selctchr);
    }
  
    
    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
       string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test';        
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        OnlstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==OnlstQuery=='+OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

     public Void doSearch(){
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }

    public void nullify(){
        lstQuery.clear();
    }
  
    public PageReference nextpage() {
       
        upsert OnlstQuery;
        
        return Page.cc;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I can't see you are assigning any values to `selctchr ` list

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selctchr}" var="eachpet">
       <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Name}" />
       <apex:column>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachpet.Good_with_Cats__c}" />
       </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Use `apex:column` to display it properly.

**Update**
use this controller code. As you are not population `selctchr`

```
public class actionSupportController {
    public List < PCS_Household__c > lstQuery {get;set;}
    public List < PCS_Household__c > OnlstQuery {get;set;}
    public List < Characteristics__c > selctchr {get;set;}
    public string ID_c {get;set;}
    public string test {get;set;}
    public List < Pets_Information__c > selctpet {get;set;}
    Public Boolean Good {get;set;}

    public actionSupportController ()
    {
          query = 'SELECT ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c=:true';
        selctchr  = database.query(query);
    }
    public void dochar() {
        string query = '';
        query = 'SELECT ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c=:true';
        Characteristics__c obj = database.query(query);
        Good = obj.Good_with_Cats__c;
    }

    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
        string Query = '';
        Query = 'SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test';
        system.debug('==Query==' + Query);
        OnlstQuery = Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery==' + OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

    public Void doSearch() {
        string Query = '';
        Query = 'SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%' + ID_c + '%\'';
        system.debug('==Query==' + Query);
        lstQuery = Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery==' + lstQuery);
    }

    public void nullify() {
        lstQuery.clear();
    }

    public PageReference nextpage() {
        upsert OnlstQuery;
        return Page.cc;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh I was still looking into the code what is issue.  you got it

Comment: no tushar. checkbox not displaying

Comment: @muralimano Did your user have permission of this field?

Comment: yes tushar.. i checked permissions are given

Comment: @muralimano Please check your updated code and screenshot of the VF page.

Comment: i have updated the latest code with screenshot

Comment: @muralimano Check my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40214/discussion-between-muralimano-and-tushar-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Tushar is correct and in addition to this you have to do couple of fixes as below in your code.

1 - In VF page your code is `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selctchr}" var="eachpet">` but in your controller you are not populating `selctchr` anywhere. Similarly for this `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selctpet}" var="eachpet">`, `selctpet` is not updated.

2 - In your command button `<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" rerender="pblck" />` you are re-rendering the block `pblck`. But no html element with id `pblck` is present in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes saroj. but my goal is i want to display checkbox custom in vf page

Comment: my custom object:Characteristics,API-Characteristics__c list of checkboxes Good_with_Cats__c,HighNeed__c,kid_friendly__c,Non_shedder__c,Predatory_Tendencies__c, i want to display these checkbox

Comment: please help me.

Comment: i have updated my controller with your code. but i am getting an error "Invalid field Gender__c for SObject Characteristics__c"

Comment: tushar what mistake i did ?

Comment: Tushar after defining the constructor i am getting this error  System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL. 
Class.actionSupportController.<init>: line 17, column 1

Answer (score 0):

you haven't put any element in your list that display in datatable i.e. selctchr. First you need to put values in this, may be in constructor then this value shows in Page.

Hope it clear your point.

Comment: if i want to populate the checkbox in pageblock not in data table means.

Comment: any comments please

Comment: My point is for both pageblock and data table.

Answer (score 0):

@murlimano, first off, we need to check if the user has permission to "Edit" a Characteristics__c record. Even if the user has a "Create" permission and not and "Edit" permission, the user will not be able to see the checkbox as we're "Editing" an existing record (the one we queried in the updated controller). Here are a couple of things you can do:

1. Check if the user has "Edit" permission in Profile / Permission set
2. Try loading the same page with another user (System Administrator preferably)
3. If the other user is able to see the checkbox and the user you're using is not, then you need to check Profile level permissions as well as FLS for the field.

Hope this helps.

Best Regards!

Comment: i cant able to view the tab in the other login but fields are set in full permission.

Comment: any one here to correct my program

Comment: The tab might not be visible for the other user, please check it on the "All Tabs" page. Also, regarding the code, it seems fine, this is definitely an issue of the permissions on profile level. Try loading the same page using a user having System Administrator profile.

Comment: now my checkboxes are visible but the query returning wrongly

Comment: hi @muralimano, could you please provide the query and results of the same?